# Facebook using koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to come to grips with using Ruby on Rails and Facebook. I'm new to Rails and I've been having a really hard time understanding a lot of the other answers already here on StackOverflow.

You can view my model user.rb here: http://pastebin.com/nckSsKWM and my view index.html.erb here: http://pastebin.com/8UXGN8Ri

What I've managed so far is to print the hash, returned from Facebook onto my view. I can get it to print out all of the data for all of my user's "friends" - but it prints this in a hash:

```
Number of friends: 2

App Friends: 

[
    {
        "uid"=>100004995550096,
        "username"=>"",
        "is_app_user"=>true
    }, 
    {
        "uid"=>100005005780053,
        "username"=>"",
        "is_app_user"=>true
    }
]
```

Two issues:

1. It is printing the data for both of this "test-account's" facebook friends. I've been trying to get it to print the data of only friends who are also using the app - in this case, it's only one of the two friends.
2. Secondly, it's returning the whole hash of data. If I only wanted to print out the username, uid, or profile picture, how would I go about doing this?

From my experience so far, I want to iterate through the hash, using a `each` block, correct me if I'm wrong, and then I want it to print out the uid "values" of all of the uids where they are already connected to my application for example. I've tried to write my own blocks, requiring the different keys, and I'm stuck. Nothing seems to work how I expect it to.

How can I iterate through a hash, and get the return value to be certain values, perhaps even using conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your original hash is a bit incorrect because both of these friends are app users.
I assume you original hash is

```
friends = [
    {
        "uid"=>100004995550096,
        "username"=>"",
        "is_app_user"=>true
    }, 
    {
        "uid"=>100005005780053,
        "username"=>"",
        "is_app_user"=>false
    }
]
```

You can take two different approaches.

1. Easier to read but a bit slower(requires two iterations).

> friends.select {|f| f["is_app_user"] }.map {|f| f["uid"]}

**Explanation:**

Select method filters array to only friends which match predicate(condition). 
The full predicate would be f["is_app_user"] == true but I used shortcut here. At the end it returns new array of items matched the predicate.
Map method performs projection to filter only fields we are interested in on already filtered array of friends.

1. Faster to read but might be a bit harder to understand especially if you're new to Ruby.

```rb
friends.inject([]) do |app_friends,friend| 
  app_friends << friend["uid"] if friend["is_app_user"]
  app_friends
end
```

**Explanation:**

Inject is a very powerful method but can be confusing sometimes to understand. 
The empty array is initial value of the app_friends variable. The way inject works is it passes to you initial value(as app_friends in our case) and expects you to perform actions on it and return new value from the block for the next iteration. The catch here if we haven't performed any action we still need to return the value that's why we have app_friends at the end.

Both of these approaches filter only app users and output uid of these users. With my assumption the output will be

> => [100004995550096]

Comment: You're right about the hash, turns out I've got the other "friend" in the database, so that makes more sense now!

Comment: So, with the first option. We're calling the select method on friends(which is taken from the fb graph?) - then passing it a block, where it sets each friend an instance variable (f) - and selects the is_app_user key values for each f (is this right?) - then we do the map method (what exactly does this do in this context? changes the format?) - maps out the uid for each "selected" f?

Comment: The second option, we're doing the inject method on friends - into an empty array? Then we're appending the friend(uid) onto said friend if said friend "is_app_user"(true) --> and then returning app_friends. Not quite sure I follow this one properly. I'll try both of these options in the morning, and let you know how I got on - it's a wee bit late - just wanted to try and understand first :). Really appreciate your time.

Comment: I have added an explanation of each of the methods.

Comment: I really appreciate that, really makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: I keep getting told that either "select" or "inject" is a private method :S

Comment: scratch that - was an error with the facebook testing account - again!